# Is there an English equivalent to "success podium"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

In sports there are three podiums for the first three top positions.

Based on it, in Persian we have some phrases (metaphors) like:

> The success podium = Success
>
> Reaching the success podium = Succeeding
>
> Standing on the success podium = Succeeding
>
> The pride podium = Success

I would like to know if such phrases are meaningful in English or if there are some equivalent phrases for them?

Comment: The winner's podium or platform. Yes. No success.

Comment: @Lambie I think you're missing the point of the question. It's about the metaphor, not simple definition.

Comment: @relaxing Is that right? I do not think the question is very clear. In any case, just about anything can be a metaphor.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+reach+the+winner%27s+podium+in+life&oq=how+to+reach+the+winner%27s+podium+in+life&aqs=chrome..69i57.7784j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Here is the same idea with winner's podium: http://www.scottstchurch.ca/blog/a-glimpse-into-eternity-reaching-out-the-winners-podium

Comment: There's nothing called "success podium" in English. I'm familiar with "in the winner's circle" as a metaphor for a particular competitive achievement, rather than for success generally. I would easily understand "on the winner's podium" as a similar metaphor for such an achievement, but it's more commonly used like, "He got onto the podium", which probably means 2nd or 3rd place -- doing very well, but not winning, or not getting exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

*Winner's circle* would be a good equivalent (from horse racing, an area where the winning horse and rider are brought to receive their award.)

In some dialects, podium also has the connotation of a speaker's stand, not necessarily for winning an award.

Example usage:

> THE WINNER'S CIRCLE
>
> In life, there is an exclusive arean I call "The Winner's CIrcle."
>   Philosophically speaking, it is an intangible, pretigious society
>   where people who consistently achieve results gain the respect of
>   others.

from *Living the Maximized Life: How to Win No Matter Where You're Starting From*
I.V. Hilliard, 2006

Some examples in book titles:

> The Winner's Circle: Wall Street's Best Mutual Fund Managers. R. J. Shook, 2005.
>
> The Winner's Circle, Yes, I Can!: Strengthening the Achievement, Motivation and Responsibility of AT-RISK Students : Resource Handbook. Clare LaMeres, 1994.

Comment: Winner's podium is very, very common.

Comment: @Lambie As a metaphor for succeeding generally? In what dialect? In Google hits winner's circle outnumbers winner's podium 5:1.

Comment: Winner's circle is a metaphor for succeeding generally? That's new to me. I fail to see the difference of winner's circle and winner's podium. And I see no metaphor in winner's circle.

Comment: Thanks, could you provide some examples?

Comment: @Ahmad Added examples.

Comment: One hit from a self-help book does not mean anything other than that author decided to use that. It does not mean one finds it all over the place as some kind of usual usage. Your claim that winner's circle would be used and winner's podium would not is false. The author could have used any number of images...

Answer (score 0):

Using

> podium
>   podium finish

implies a top three finish, since otherwise there is no podium.

This is used more in BrE than AmE.  The AmE equivalent is

> top three finish

[Ormerod and Morgan grab World Cup podium finishes](https://www.teamgb.com/news/ormerod-and-morgan-grab-world-cup-podium-finishes)